# Strange powershell behaviour with script blocks and regex replace

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use `[regex]::Replace` with a match evaluator to selectively replace parts of a string. I'm writing and debugging the function in PowerShell ISE. What is strange is that running the replacement code causes one machine to output a string that is the content of the match evaluator script block while the other replaces the text correctly. I had no clue this was even possible nor why it is happening.

Given this code (borrowed from another stackoverflow answer):

```bsh
$global_counter = 0
$callback = {
    $global_counter += 1
    "string-$($args[0])-" + $global_counter
}

$re = [regex]"match"
$re.Replace('zzz match match xxx', $callback)
```

Executing it on one machine causes the output (PowerShell Version `5.1.18362.145`):

```
zzz string-match-1 string-match-1 xxx
```

But on another it outputs (PowerShell Version `5.1.17134.858`):

```
zzz
    $global_counter += 1
    "string-$($args[0])-" + $global_counter

    $global_counter += 1
    "string-$($args[0])-" + $global_counter
 xxx
```

Both are running in an x64 PowerShell ISE clean instance directly from reboot. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: As an aside, on PowerShell 2, the output is actually `zzz string-match-1 string-match-2 xxx`, showing the difference between how the closures are treated. To get the same output in v5, the variable needs to be scoped (`$script:global_counter += 1`).

Comment: I have no machine available with the specific version that exhibits the delegate conversion problem, but what happens if you give your callback an explicit parameter (`$callback = { param($m) ... }`) and use that rather than `$args`?

Comment: Alternatively, is anything different if you add an explicit conversion operation/type annotation  (`[System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator] $callback`)? Apparently an untoward conversion to `string` happens because the engine picks the wrong overload, and while I don't know why, an explicit conversion should at least avoid it from happening and offer consistent behavior across versions.

Comment: @jerone Adding an explicit param did not help, but specifying the type threw an error "Only core types are supported in this language mode". As a test I tried running the ISE as an admin and here it works fine. I'm guessing the script block is converted to string due to the language mode and then it's applied to the replacer. Thanks for helping me debug the issue. If you want the credit feel free to write up a quick answer. Otherwise I'll add one myself.

Comment: Aha! Well then today I learned there is actually such a thing as [constrained language mode](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-constrained-language-mode/). That would indeed explain the behavior you see. I'm still not completely clear on how you configure the policies that govern this and whether that's a version difference or just a configuration difference between the machines (my ISE, starting as a non-admin, does not constrain the language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With debugging help from Jeroen I've managed to figure out why this is happening.

PowerShell has a security feature called Constrained Language Mode that prevents the use of any, but a core set of whitelisted types. What appears to be happening is that I'm defining a scriptblock that in turn is converted to a `System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator` before being passed to the `Replace` function. The match evaluator however is outside of this core set of types which means when the PowerShell engine tries to coerce the type onto an overload of `Replace` the only other valid one is `Replace(string, string, string)` (thanks Jeroen for pointing this out in the comments). The `Replace` function does its job, but with a regular string as a replacement thus resulting in the odd behaviour.

I'm not able to alter the language mode of my PowerShell session on the machine I'm currently working with as it is applied through Group Policies, but a workaround for me at least was to use an elevated PowerShell session and ISE to test my script.

Comment: The reason it's treated as a string is because, when the conversion to `MatchEvaluator` is taken off the table, the only other candidate overload with two arguments is `Regex.Replace(string, string)`, and so that is invoked with an implicit conversion on the script block. Had that overload not existed, the invocation would have been an error.

Comment: As a fun aside, this same issue is also preventing me from setting breakpoints while writing scripts in a non-elevated PowerShell ISE.

Comment: From what I've read, constrained language mode is so absurdly constrained that it's a wonder you can do anything at all. It seems like an interesting experiment but not a very useful one -- in scenarios where anyone would consider using it, you're probably better off not allowing (unsigned) scripts at all, which gives much more predictable behavior.